# Cofinality without choice: can this coarse definition suffer badly?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, order-theory, axiom-of-choice

*This is a rephrased version of a question previously [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032697/weird-cofinality-behavior-without-choice) without success.*

---

Working in $\mathsf{ZF}$, it is no longer possible in general to give every linear order an *ordinal* cofinality. For example, an infinite Dedekind-finite set of reals without a greatest element (viewed as a linear order) has no cofinal well-orderable suborder, and such sets exist in Cohen's original model of $\neg\mathsf{AC}$. The obvious way to generalize the notion of cofinality is by looking at the isomorphism types of cofinal suborders.

However, we could also define a simpler if less informative invariant by looking merely at the *cardinalities* of the cofinal suborders. I'm interested in how much information is lost when we shift from the former to the latter, and in particular whether a certain extreme loss of information is consistent:

> Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are linear orders $X,Y$ such that
>
> 1. every cofinal subset of $X$ is in (non-order-preserving) bijection with some cofinal subset of $Y$ and every cofinal subset of $Y$ is in (non-order-preserving) bijection with some cofinal subset of $X$, but
> 2. there is no linear order $Z$ which cofinally embeds into both $X$ and $Y$?

Obviously such $X$ and $Y$ must have the same (choiceless) cardinality, and neither can have a well-orderable cofinal subset. Beyond that, I don't see anything useful.

I vaguely recall that this is indeed possible (and that we can take $X$ and $Y$ to be suborders of $\mathbb{R}$), but can't find a citation for this. My memory is that the proof is rather hard, FWIW.